# К задать интервал между спавном объектов?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Привет. Есть такой код -

```
 void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("x") && flaresCount > 0)
    {
        SpawnFlares();
    }
}
void SpawnFlares()
{
    { 
        for (int i = 50; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (!FlareInCountdown)
            {
                GameObject flareLeft = Instantiate(flare, leftSpawner.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                GameObject flareRight = Instantiate(flare, rightSpawner.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                flareLeft.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.right * Random.Range(2, 5) + new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, -1), 0));
                flareRight.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-transform.right * Random.Range(2, 5) + new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, -1), 0));
                StartCoroutine(FlareCountdown());
            }
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator FlareCountdown()
{
    FlareInCountdown = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1F);
    FlareInCountdown = false;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы все 50 объектов заспавнились через определенный интервал. То-есть по одному слева и справа спавнится, проходит 0,1 секунды и опять спавн и так далее. Но у меня спавниться только два объекта. Пробовал переставлять, местами, проверку и цикл, но не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы, видимо, не совсем понимаете, что у вас происходит.
Коррутина выполняется отдельно от основного метода после её вызова. Т.е. вы один раз спауните объекты, потом стартуете корутину, которая выставляет флаг на false и засыпает на 0.1f секунду.

Тем временем метод продолжает выполнение, проверяет в том же кадре ещё 49 раз флаг, 49 раз получает false и заканчивает цикл.
Все эти проверки не занимают десятой секунды и потому больше ничего не спаунится, т.к. корутина не успевает проснуться и изменить флаг.

Решением будет сделать сам метод SpawnFlares тоже корутиной. При вызове внутре корутины другой корутины с приставкой yield return текущая передаст управление внутрь вызванной и заснёт до окончания её выполнения. Т.е. вам нужен следующий код:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("x") && flaresCount > 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnFlares());
    }
}

IEnumerator SpawnFlares()
{
        for (int i = 50; i > 0; i--)
        {
                GameObject flareLeft = Instantiate(flare, leftSpawner.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                GameObject flareRight = Instantiate(flare, rightSpawner.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                flareLeft.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.right * Random.Range(2, 5) + new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, -1), 0));
                flareRight.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-transform.right * Random.Range(2, 5) + new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, -1), 0));
                yield return StartCoroutine(FlareCountdown());
        }
}

IEnumerator FlareCountdown()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1F);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.  Можно ведь без FlareCountdown. yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1F); вставить вместо  yield return StartCoroutine(FlareCountdown());

Comment: @xomem, да, вы правы. Писал ответ на уставшую голову, просто сократил лишнее, а то, что целый метод лишний не додумал)